# Unable to get timezone abbreavation using moment-timezone

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs, timezone-offset, moment-timezone

I am using moment-timezone to get the abbreviation for the user's timezone.
Following is the code used to find the abbreviation

```
var timeZone = moment.tz.guess(true);
var time = new Date();
var timeZoneOffset = time.getTimezoneOffset();
var abbr  = moment.tz.zone(timeZone).abbr(timeZoneOffset);
alert(timeZone+": " + abbr);
```

This alerts fine for few timezones.
But for the timezone **`America/La_Paz`**, I am getting abbreviation as **`-04`**.
Do I need to update my code or is there any other way to get the correct (3-character like) abbreviation?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

your code is correct, but moment-timezone does not store alphabetical abbreviations for all timezones:

[image]

compared to America/Los_Angeles:

[image]

America/La_Paz has actually in moment-timezone by default no alphabetical abbreviation, just UTC-4.

You can change this abbreviation to whatever you want by:

```
var pazZone = moment.tz.zone("America/La_Paz");
pazZone.abbrs = ["BOT"]
moment.tz([2012, 5], 'America/La_Paz').format('z'); // => BOT
```

Comment: But La_Paz follows Bolivia's time (BOT - abbreviation) 
[link](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/bolivia). 
Is this data not present in moment? 
Is there any other possible way to get timezone abbreviation as per my requirement ?

Comment: no this abbreviation is not present in moment-timezone by default. you can change it as shown in the updated post. is this the only timezone where you are missing data?

Comment: No, there are many other timezones. 
For the workaround, I took all the timezone names from the windows tzutils and took the timezone (like Aisa/calcuuta format) & abbreviation for each using moment-timezone and updated the abbreviation manually for those timezones with UTC+/-hh:mm format as abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

Not all timezones have short abbreviations. Here is the list of all possible timezones and abbreviations [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), [AWS dev-database](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/time-zone-abbrevs.html), PHP [datetime parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), etc.[image]

So, my workaround is something like:

```
//initialization:
let eventDate = '2023-04-06T00:00:00+00:00'; //any dynamic value
let visitorTz = moment.tz.guess();
let momentDateTime = moment.utc(eventDate).tz(visitorTz);
let displayFormat = "ddd, MMM DD, YYYY h:mm A"; //Tz abbr will be appended;

//compare first 3 letters to check if abbr available for this timezone:
let z1 = momentDateTime.format('Z'); //'+06:00'
let z2 = momentDateTime.format('z'); //PDT|AEST|IST|'+06'
let tzAbbr = (z1.substring(0,3)==z2.substring(0,3))? ' ('+z1+' GMT)' : ' ('+z2+')';

//output:
let formatted = momentDateTime.format(displayFormat) + tzAbbr;
console.log( formatted );

//Expected result (showing only the Abbr part)
When Australia/Melbourne (+10:00 GMT) ==> (AEST)
When Asia/Karachi (+05:00 GMT) ==> (PKT)
When Asia/Kolkatta (+05:30 GMT) ==> (IST)
When Asia/Dhaka (+06:00 GMT) ==> (+06:00 GMT) //not available
```

We can also directly try to see what the moment outputs for any specific timezone:

```
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('z'); //PDT
```