# Not getting abbreviation for some IANA names in moment-timezone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, momentjs, moment-timezone

moment-timezone library

```
moment().tz("Pacific/Kiritimati").zoneAbbr() // results to +14, shouldn't this be LINT?
moment().tz("Asia/Kolkata").zoneAbbr() // results to IST which is correct
```

I'm confused shouldn't we get `LINT` for `Pacific/Kiritimati`, or, is it possible to get that using moment-timezone?

Here's the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/moment-timezone-test-3ekwq?file=/src/index.js) link.

Comment: I think the answer to the question is exactly here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40495632/5562701

Comment: Yes exactly @OzanManav, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Tried to answer similar [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60651823/unable-to-get-timezone-abbreavation-using-moment-timezone/73849743#73849743)